# js not running when using httpservice

Tags: javascript, php

I am using ROBLOX's http postasync method to update data on my site. I am attempting to send a webhook to discord when the php scrip runs and the required material is presented... However the script part of the php file does not run unless I manually load the page.

```
<?php
        $token = $_POST["token"];
        $type = $_POST["type"];
        $pid = $_POST["pid"];
        $sid = $_POST["sid"];
        $gid = $_POST["gid"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $players = $_POST["players"];
        $max = $_POST["max"];
        $cdesc = $_POST["cdesc"];
        $sus = $_POST["sus"];
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function sendLog(){ 
    var hookurl = "***"
    tosend = [
    '**Server added;**',
    'Game Name: <?php echo(json_encode($name)); ?>',
    'Game ID: <?php echo(json_encode($gid)); ?>',
    'Server ID: <?php echo(json_encode($sid)); ?>',
    ],
    msgJson = {
         "attachments": [
        {
            "color": "#CC09EF",
            "text": tosend.join('\n'),
            "footer": "Infius Game Logs",
            "footer_icon": "http://deersystems.net/assets/images/nfius.png",
        }
    ]
        }
  post(hookurl, msgJson); 
  }

function post(url, jsonmsg){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
         var data = JSON.stringify(jsonmsg);
          xhr.send(data);
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.status != 200){
            alert("ttt");
         }
          }
       }
     </script>

      <?php
      if($type == 'add' and $sid !=NULL and $gid !=NULL and $name!=NULL and $players !=NULL){
        echo "
        <script type="text/javascript">
                sendLog();
        </script>
        ";
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @nicovank I cant really check, as I said Im sending http post request using roblox's system... but it works when I manually pull up the page.

Comment: bumb :/ .-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-